# how to fix browser mode in a previous version IE10

Tags: internet-explorer

If I you go developer tools in IE10 or IE9 you can change Browser Mode to a previous IE version.
The problem is that when I submit the page and the new page retrieved, it is shown in latest IE browser mode.
Is it possible to fix (or default) the browser mode for every request to be shown in a previous IE version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to force IE to use an older rendering mode, you can put an `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag, as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" >
```

However, in general it's not a good idea to use compatibility mode. There are very few reasons to ever want to use it.

If your site looks better in compatibility mode than it does in IE10 mode then there is likely to be something in your page that needs to be fixed to work properly in IE10, rather than forcing IE to go backwards -- IE10 is pretty good at being standards-compliant, so if your code doesn't work in IE10 but does work in compatibility mode, then it is likely to have problems in other browsers as well.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Actually I realized that if I change compatibility mode for a tab and I stay in the same one, all pages retrieved stay in the same mode. The problem is when I open a new Tab or window

Answer (score 0):

Yes add the following META tag to your page's header (using the target version # of course)

You can also tell IE what engine to use in the Http Header as well, the META tag overrides the Http header, FYI.

Just for the record you should always use the latest version. The ability to target outdated versions is simply a feature, mostly for enterprise applications and developers to test backward compatibility.